# Characterizing the tangent line of a multivariable polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to learn algebraic geometry at a basic level and came across this problem:

> Let $K$ be a field. For $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$, a line $L$ in $K^2$ is called a tangent line of the curve $V(f)$ at a point $P=(a,b)\in V(f)$ if $f$ restricted to the line $L$ has a multiple root at $P$. Apply Taylor's theorem to the polynomial $f$ to show that if either of the partial derivatives of $f$ are nonzero at $P$ then the unique tangent line to $V(f)$ at $P$ is the line
>   $$V\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)(x-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P)(y-b)\right) (*)$$
>   A curve is called nonsingular at $P$ if it has a unique tangent line at $P$. Find all the tangent lines to the curves $V(y^2-x^3)$ and $V(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ at $(0,0)$ and explain why they are singular at this point.

I should mention (just to be complete) that for a polynomial $f\in K[x,y]$, $V(f)=\lbrace P\in K^2|f(P)=0 \rbrace$.

My main issues with this problem are that I can't find a consistent statement of Taylor's theorem for two variables, and similarly, I can't find a definition for a multiple root of a two-variable polynomial.

Either way, I have the book "Elementary Algebraic Geometry" by Klaus Hulek, and he solves a similar problem in section 3.1. His approach was to parametrize a line to reduce it to a problem of one variable, but again, the problem with multiple roots seems to arise. Nevertheless, here's my attempt at a start:

A line $L$ in $K^2$ can be parametrized as $(x,y)=(t,m(t-a)+b)$. Then $f(x,y)$ restricted to $L$ has the form $f(t,m(t-a)+b)$. Taylor's theorem states that $$f(x,y)=f(P)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)(x-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P)(y-b)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(P)(x-a)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(P)(y-b)^2+...$$
$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)(x-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P)(y-b)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(P)(x-a)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(P)(y-b)^2+...$$
since $P\in V(f)\Rightarrow f(P)=0$.

So, $f$ restricted to the line $L$ can be expressed with the above series via the change of variables $x\mapsto t,y\mapsto m(t-a)+b$:
$$f(t,m(t-a)+b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(P)(t-a)+m\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(P)(m(t-a))+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}(P)(t-a)^2+0\cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}(P)(m(t-a))^2+...$$

I don't want to continue until I know if this is a good approach or not. Also, what happens to the higher order terms in Taylor's theorem? Sorry that my work is not complete - I'm a bit frustrated with the problem at the moment.